# multiple queries in one mysql connection fail to be run with php

Tags: php, ajax, json, web

Here is a part of my php code:

```
 foreach ($value->ahkam as $k => $v){
        echo $v->id."\n";
        //Save into db one hokm
        $addHokm = "INSERT INTO qm_hokm (hokm_id, type, tooltip, line, x1, y1, x2, y2, radius, XOrigin, YOrigin, page_id)
            VALUES ($v->id,$v->type,'tooltip',0,$v->x1,$v->y1,$v->x2,$v->y2,$v->r,$v->XOrigin,$v->YOrigin,$pageNumber)";
        if(!mysqli_query($con, $addHokm))
            echo "Failed to insert into db...".$v->id."\n";
    }
```

In fact, I am fetching a json structure sent by an ajax request from a client.
I have many values in `$value->ahkam` but the problem is that only the first query is run and the others give me the error msg. Any help plz

UPDATE:

the result of echo is:

```
0
1
Failed to insert into db...1
2
Failed to insert into db...2
```

As you see, the `hokm` number 0 is added but not the others, I need to mention also that `$pageNumer` is a `foeign key`

Comment: This is impossible to troubleshoot without knowing what the actual error is.  I would include the error message generated by mysqli_query.

Comment: You need to read the [mysqli_query man page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). The first parameter is the query, not the connection.

Comment: The error you are posting is one you are generating. What is the database showing you?  I'm not very familiar with mysqli, but I think mysqli_error will show you that error.

Comment: @Mike i have corrected it but the same problem : (

Comment: @Robbert u re right: mysqli->error gave me "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'page_id'". page_id is a foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your foreign key, it must not be `unique`.  Like that, you can add multiple entries for one `page_id`. I hope it is the correct answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it appears that your query is inserting a duplicate value for the page_id value, which appears to be set as a field that cannot have duplicate values.  According to your query, you're using $pageNumber for that field, but I don't see it changing in your loop.  You either need to get rid of the constraint preventing you from using the same value or make sure that $pageNumber has a value that isn't being used already.